# Java program to connect multiple TCP servers at run time

Tags: java, tcp

I have web application which will display all my TCP servers (N number of servers) in the drop down, user will select any one server along with message and user will submit the request, the request will come to my system through REST call and my system should have provision to connect the server immediately through TCP and have to send that message. This scenario will happen very rarely. So my connection to that server should be closed after sending message.

I have another requirement like have to create TCP server using Java and N number of clients will connect my server and they will send message for every seconds. This connection should be open until client closes, but this will happen only when client system down.

I would prefer to go with spring boot because will deploy this application using docker.

I do not have any idea about this, so I need any reference or sample to implement. First I need approach and then need a reference to meet my requirement?

Will use any queue system (Activemq, Rabbitmq, Kafka) to listen TCP request and will consume that message from queue using spring boot?

Comment: Sounds cool! :) But *what/where* is the question?? How can we help You? :)

Comment: I do not have any idea about this, so I need any reference or sample to implement. First I need approach and then need a reference to meet my requirement.

Comment: ZeroMQ can help. Otherwise you just need Java `SocketServer`. And FWIW, Docker has nothing to do with Spring ; any Java app can be put in Docker containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just thinking out loud here:
In the first scenario you don't really need to know the item from the list has anything to do with a TCP connection until you actually go to make the connection.  Until then it's a hostname from a list you pulled from a database query.  At the point of connection it's a simple connect() to a given host and do what you need.

In the second scenario I think perhaps you'd be better served using a UDP service.  In this case the server would simply get a queue of messages from the various clients.  If you use TCP each client forces its own channel (port mapping) so that every channel has only one client.  You are then forced to use either select() to choose a connection to service, or write your app multithreaded to service them all at once upon connection.  UDP is just simpler.

Answer (score 0):

> I have web application which will display all my TCP servers (N number of servers) in the drop down

This is commonly implemented using **Service Discovery**. Consul, etcd, Zookeeper, here are some examples.

> the request will come to my system through REST call and my system should have provision to connect the server immediately through TCP and have to send that message

That is just the nature of an open socket. By "REST", I assume you are using HTTP, then, not raw TCP.

> have to create TCP server using Java and N number of clients will connect my server and they will send message for every seconds

Again, you are hosting an **HTTP server**, and like any "website", you have thousands of clients that send requests.

> connection should be open until client closes

Why?

---

Queues would only help if your (HTTP) service goes down, or cannot handle increased load from more clients, **and** you can guarantee the queue has higher uptime and maintenance than your own service.